# How to select all inputs by name?

Tags: javascript

I know you can use this to get all elements with the name 'target':

```
document.getElementsByName('target')
```

But what if I want to select only inputs with that name?

Comment: Loop through the returned elements, check the tagName. Or use jQuery and analogous frameworks.

Comment: I didn't even know `getElementsByName()`. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=target]");
```

Comment: Sorry, I've mistyped.

Answer (score 5):

In pure JavaScript you can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="target"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can catch `forms` by `name` you can do

```
<form name="outerTarget">    
    <input type="button" value="test" name="target">
</form>
<script>
document.forms['outerTarget'].target;
</script>
```

#### MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name#Example.